# How to pass a razor variable to jquery function as parameter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am having the following piece of code that is not working:

`<a href="#" onclick="Edit(@Interest);">edit</a>`

where  I have

`@{string Interest=""}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to quote the string like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="Edit('@Interest');">edit</a>
```

Comment: it`s firing error with Edit('@Interest'); error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'Interest'

Comment: The compiler is probably right - assign a value before using the variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call a method e.g. @Url.Action("test") for an action link, then you have to use it like:

```
<a href='@(Url.Action("test"))'>test</a>
```

Otherwise korchev's solution is right.