# how to pass a razor value to a jquery function, in an mvc view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, parameter-passing

So I'm trying to pass a parameter to a javascript function using the razor '@' notation (in an MVC-4 View) but I'm getting Syntax error: "Unterminated string constant"

Is there another way I should be writing this?

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
 ...
    <input type="button" value="Assign" onclick="AssignButtonClicked('@item.ID')" />
}
```

I've used the same syntax as this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5179316/1662619

Edit:

It's just a syntax error, the functionality still works

Comment: Solution:- remove the single quotation around @item.ID

Comment: Instead of single-quotation, it's better to use of backtick(`) in javascript. this answer completely describes it. [backticks in razor pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54052399/7487135)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you can use [JQuery](http://jquery.com) [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
<input type="button" value="Assign" onclick="AssignButtonClicked(this)" 
       data-assigned-id="@item.ID" />
```

Further it can be fetched using

```
function AssignButtonClicked(elem){
     var id= $(elem).data('assigned-id');
}
```

Answer (score 14):

try this

```
 <input type="button" value="Assign"
   onclick="@("AssignButtonClicked('"+item.ID+"')")"  />
```

Comment: This answer worked for me, all though it was very painful to actually commit this code because readability is -10!

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
 <input type="button" value="Assign" onclick="AssignButtonClicked(@item.ID);" />
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 function AssignButtonClicked(obj) {
        alert(obj);
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @Jim Barton It's perfectly working on my project.Can you show some code for `foreach` loop.

Comment: The input tag is inside a <tr> <td> <input... /> </td> </tr> if that makes a difference? The rest of the loop just consists of <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Forename)</td> rows etc..

Comment: @Jim Barton  unterminated string constant is beacause of missing a closing quotation mark.pretty sure you have made some mistake in the syntax.Check your `table`and your `foreach` loop i think you missing some `tr`,`td` or `some tag`.

Answer (score 2):

As alternative, you may use the other way to get `@item.ID` in your jQuery function. Just add hiden span with it and get it's value in your function.

Say, you have list:

```
<ul>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
 ...
   <li> <input type="button" value="Assign" onclick="AssignButtonClicked()" />
        <span class="hidenID">@item.ID</span>
</li>
}
</ul>
```

than in your script add:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.hidenID').hide() //**hide your span
});

function AssignButtonClicked()
{
...
var id = $(this).closest('li').find('.hidenID').text();
...
}

</script>
```

But to my mind better approach for jQuery is as follows:

```
    <ul>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
         ...
           <li> <input type="button" value="Assign" class="button" />
                <span class="hidenID">@item.ID</span>
        </li>
        }
        </ul>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.hidenID').hide() //**hide your span
        });

        $(function(){
         $('.button').click(function(){
        ...
         var id = $(this).closest('li').find('.hidenID').text();
        ...
        }
    });

});

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You tried with:

```
<input type="button" value="Assign" onclick="AssignButtonClicked('@item.ID');" />
```

I added a semicolon at the end of javascript function call `AssignButtonClicked('@item.ID');`

Comment: Syntax error. Mine is `onclick = "javascript:alert('@Model.username.ToString()');" `

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this kind of issue, you may build all your js function call in c# code section.

Instead of:

```
<input type="button" value="Assign" onclick="AssignButtonClicked('@item.ID')" />
```

Use:

```
@{
  var assignFunctionCall = "AssignButtonClicked(" + item.ID + ")";
}
<input type="button" value="Assign" onclick="@assignFunctionCall " />
```