# Pass Razor Model From Foreach To jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Okay so I'm iterating over models with a Razor foreach, and I'd like to send the model to jQuery. I can send individual parameters [as seen in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18311503/how-to-pass-a-razor-value-to-a-jquery-function-in-an-mvc-view), but not the full object.

Example:

```
<table>
@foreach (var contact in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#" onclick="myFunction('@contact.Name')">@contact.Name</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" onclick="myFunction('@contact.Company')">@contact.Company.Name</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction(contact) {
        console.log(contact);
    };
</script>
```

Here, sending `@contact.Name` will send the value in `Name` to the function as expected, but `@contact.Company` (which is a Company object, rather than a string) will send the string value `ProjectName.Models.Company`. Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do?

Here's an example of one of the actual models I'm using (note that every model I use, like this one, also has another object type as a field).

```
 public class Note
 {
   public long NoteId { get; set; }
   public string Content { get; set; }
   public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
   public User CreatedBy { get; set; } 
 }
```

Comment: Do you want to send the `Company` model to the function (so you can access all the properties of `Company`, or do you just want to send the `Company.Name` property?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has no concept of your model, but your can encode it and parse it to a javascript object so that you access its properties in your script

```
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction(JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(contact.Company))'))">@contact.Company.Name</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction(company) {
    console.log(company.Name);
  };
</script>
```

Comment: This is actually throwing an error for me (`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`). If I call `JSON.parse` in the JS function, rather than inline, it works fine.

Comment: Then its because of another issue. If you post you model for `Company`  I can have a look. (Note the 'link only answer' will probably be deleted by the moderators)

Comment: Yep, sure thing. I added one of my models to the bottom. I also noted that all of the models I'm using have other objects as fields within them, wasn't sure if that might be the cause of the error.

Comment: That should not be a problem. If `Note` is a property of `contact` and  you use `onclick="myFunction(JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(contact.Note))'))", then in the script, add `console.log(company);` you should see something like `Object {NoteId : 1, Content : "Some text", CreatedBy: Object}` (and you could expand `CreatedBy` to see the properties of `User`). One thing that may cause an issue is if you have any circular references. For example `Note` has a property for `User` which has a property for `Note`.