# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I have a razor syntax like this:

```
   foreach(var item in model)
 {
<td><a href ="#"  onclick="Getinfo(@item.email);" >6/16/2016 2:02:29 AM</a>  </td>
 }
```

My javascript that recieves the request goes like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Getinfo(elem) {
        var email = document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML;
    }
</script>
```

When clicking on the href link, I get the following error in the console of the browser:

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token",

and this part is underlined:

```
    **</a>  </td>**
```

I am a beginner so I get stuck in syntax a lot. If it is that then please help me out.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You should pass `@item.email` in quotes then it will be treated as string argument

```
<td><a href ="#"  onclick="Getinfo('@item.email');" >6/16/2016 2:02:29 AM</a>  </td>
```

Otherwise, it is treated as variable thus error is generated.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. I was using ruby on rails and was facing the same error

Answer (score 16):

The accepted answer work when you have a single line string(the email) but if you have a

multiline string, the error will remain.

Please look into this matter:

```
<!-- start: definition-->
@{
    dynamic item = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
    item.MultiLineString = @"a multi-line
                             string";
    item.SingleLineString = "a single-line string";
}
<!-- end: definition-->
<a href="#" onclick="Getinfo('@item.MultiLineString')">6/16/2016 2:02:29 AM</a>
<script>
    function Getinfo(text) {
        alert(text);
    }
</script>
```

Change the single-quote(') to backtick(`) in Getinfo as bellow and error will be fixed:

```
<a href="#" onclick="Getinfo(`@item.MultiLineString`)">6/16/2016 2:02:29 AM</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had an issue with multiline strings in this scenario. @Iman's backtick(`) solution worked great in the modern browsers but caused an invalid character error in Internet Explorer. I had to use the following:

```
'@item.MultiLineString.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />")'
```

Then I had to put the carriage returns back again in the js function. Had to use RegEx to handle multiple carriage returns.

```
// This will work for the following:
// "hello\nworld"
// "hello<br>world"
// "hello<br />world"
$("#MyTextArea").val(multiLineString.replace(/\n|<br\s*\/?>/gi, "\r"));
```