# When exactly to use quotes in composite string formatting with razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

This [string formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37858370/uncaught-syntaxerror-invalid-or-unexpected-token) answer solved my problem, but doesn't explain why razor syntax in string formatting works in the following way...

```
<button type="button" onclick="wea.open('editDinner', {params: {id: @o.Id }})" class="wea-btn">
```

works without causing an js error IF @o.Id is an integer type, but when changed to a GUID type then single quotes around the razor syntax are required ...

```
<button type="button" onclick="wea.open('editDinner', {params: {id: '@o.Id' }})" class="wea-btn">
```

which is identical except for the single quotes around  @o.Id .

Is the razor syntax here treated differently based on the property type (int vs Guid)?  When should quotes be used and why?

Comment: That has nothing to do with Razor, that's just how Json works, you'd need those quotes even if you used a code coded value instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example, it's the JavaScript syntax rules that dictate the quote usage (not the Razor rules). With a simple integer the object can be parsed; but the GUID produces invalid JavaScript so you need the quotes.

```
{ id: 1 }  // ok
{ id: 35aa3122-7d73-4758-ac00-f4150f289767 } // invalid js
```

Comment: so JS needs to treat the Guid as a string?

Comment: If you interpolate your Razor statement you end up with invalid JavaScript.