# CryptoJS error when posting content with new line

Tags: javascript

Whenever I submit a textarea element where I have typed content with Enter (a new line) it gives me the error: 
**Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token**

```
    var jft = localStorage.getItem("jft");
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("<?php echo $_POST['value']; ?>", jft);
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: `encrypt(<?= json_encode($_POST['value']); ?>,`

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37858370/uncaught-syntaxerror-invalid-or-unexpected-token)